# Problem with foreign key in Entity Framework one to many

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having some foreign key problems, it turns out that I am doing a revision to an old system in which a new table is added, and in doing so, the following arises.

In short, I have the following 3 classes.

```
public class StepUp
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]    
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }    
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accesorio_x_Trafos> Accesorios { get; set; }
    //More irrelevant properties..
}

public class Transformador 
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accesorio_x_Trafos> Accesorio_x_Trafos { get; set; }
    //More irrelevant properties..
}

public class Accesorio_x_Trafos
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string CodigoAccesorio { get; set; }        
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }       
    public int? Cantidad { get; set; }    
}
```

The issue is that both `StepUp` and `Transformador` have a 1- * relationship with `Accessorio_x_Trafos`.

When migrating, the database is created correctly (FKs are added)

[image]

(Ignore the FK `Accesorios` which is one of the properties that I removed so as not to have so much code)

The issue is that when I try, both modify an object of type Transformer (I do it as follows)

```
//Get any object..
var transformador = mContext.Transformador.First();
//Add random data..
transformador.Accesorio_x_Trafos = new List<Accesorio_x_Trafos>
{
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos 
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 1, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000802000P0800"},
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 2, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000803150P0700"},
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 3, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000803150P0700"}
};
//Save it
mContext.SaveChanges();
```

But this throws the follow exception

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while...

And in the InnerException the

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY
>   \"FK_dbo.Accesorio_x_Trafos_dbo.StepUps_CodigoDelfos_Revision\". El
>   conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos \"DBTrafos\", tabla
>   \"dbo.StepUps\".\r\nSe terminó la instrucción.

How can i deal with this?

Comment: You should have a StepUp and Transformador object in Accesorio_x_Trafos and then setup the FK mappings (or use fluent code) to each. Not sure how to do that with your composite key structure.

Comment: @SteveGreene Ty for answer, so, should i have one object of many clases that use Accesorio_x_Trafos collections?

Comment: Yes, here is a simple Student with multiple Grades example. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue by creating an abstract class that replaced `Accessory_x_Trafos` in such a way, that you then specify each inherited class with its foreign key and corresponding navigation property.

```
public abstract class AccesorioTransformador
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CodigoAccesorio { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }   
}

public class AccesorioStepUp : AccesorioTransformador
{
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }   
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CodigoDelfos)+","+nameof(Revision))]   
    public StepUp.StepUp Transformador { get; set; }
}

public class AccesorioDistribucion : AccesorioTransformador
{
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }           
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CodigoDelfos) + "," + nameof(Revision))]
    public Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, in each of the corresponding classes, I used properties, either type `ICollection<AccesorioStepUp>` or type `ICollection<AccesorioDistribucion>`.